# How do I get the World's Best Dad achievement?

Tags: achievements, jurassic-park-2011

The World's Best Dad achievement's description is "Say things to Jess that no parent should ever say," with a counter for 3 things.

What things do I need to say to her to get this achievement?

For that matter, are all 3 things in Episode 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this site](http://www.trueachievements.com/a156050/worlds-best-dad-achievement.htm):

> The achievement requires you to say three things parents should never
>   say to their children.
>
> When you're in the jeep before finding Nima you have to tell her that
>   her mother was overreacting when discussing her problems at home.
>
> Once you're safely inside the bunker after the T-Rex and Triceratops
>   fight you have to answer "Maybe" when she asks if the dinosaurs can
>   get inside the bunker.
>
> Lastly, when she's hanging on the ledge above the door tell her "Don't
>   be stupid" and the achievement will pop.

Comment: Apparently it also has to be done in a complete Episode 1 playthrough, as doing the Scenarios individually resets the achievement counter (at least on Steam it does).